# Group list of dicts by value, then group some nested dicts

Tags: python, django

I've got data like this:

```
plans = [
  {'code':1, 'name':'Station1', 'plan_type':2, 'layer':1, 'hour':1, 'val':23.34}
  {'code':1, 'name':'Station1', 'plan_type':2, 'layer':1, 'hour':2, 'val':33.34}
  {'code':2, 'name':'Station2', 'plan_type':2, 'layer':1, 'hour':1, 'val':23.34}
  {'code':2, 'name':'Station2', 'plan_type':2, 'layer':1, 'hour':1, 'val':23.34}
....
  {'code':2, 'name':'Station2', 'plan_type':2, 'layer':1, 'hour':1, 'val':23.34}
]
```

It describes production plans. What I'm trying to get to display it on Django template is

```
 { <code>:{'name':<name>,
            <plan_type>:{<hour>:{'layer':<layer>,'val':<val>} ... }
          }
 }
```

Which means group data by code, set group a name, then group by plan type, and for each plan use hours as keys to discribe layers and values in the layers.
I tried list comprehension

```
   a = { plan['code']:{
            'name':plan['name'],
            p['plan_type']:None for p in plans if p['code'] == plan['code']
        } for plan in plans }
```

Can't get past this. There's syntax error. I can either get codes for plan types as keys for nested dict or set 'name' value. There are solution with *defaultdict* and *itertools*, but I have yet to figure out how to apply them.
This works, but isn't exactly I try to achieve:

```
   a = { plan['code']:{
            'name':plan['name'],
            'plan':{p['plan_type']:None} for p in plans if p['code'] == plan['code']
        } for plan in plans }
```

Comment: Why don't you do the complex structuring in python? Then just pass in an object to the template.

Comment: One quick problem is `p['code'] == plans['code']`   .
  

`plans['code']` should be `plan['code']`, right?

Comment: I would have just put this thing in pandas and gotten the html code. Also using functions is better than overnested list/dict comprehensions.

Comment: This will never work. You are assigning keys based on the value of `code`, however, the value of `code` repeats so, you will only ever get the values of the last repetition.

Comment: @VisheshMangla yes, plans['code'] is a typo, was writing this a bit late, and where do I read about how to solve that with functions?

Comment: @jcfollower yup, a typo

Comment: Do one thing for now, that plz write the normal for loop by initializing empty dict and appending to it.No fancy python

Comment: Also see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

Comment: @VisheshMangla I tried regroup in a template, but I was hopeing to avoid it and yes, you might be right. Thank you.

Comment: well, if you want to avoid inbuilt stuff, then you need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct in assuming you just want to produce the resulting dict in a template:

I wonder if the best thing here is to use filters?
It's a bit complex, but you could extract each level using a filter once a dict has been generated.
The challenge is a filter can only accept one argument so you'd have to encode both the "path to your entry" and what you're extracting somehow, as well as chain invocations...

Something I doodled up is the following:

Somewhere in your code somewhere you register a filter:

```
from typing import List, Dict, Any
from django import template

register = template.Library()

...

@register.filter
def extract_and_group(entries: List[Dict[str, Any]], attribute: str) -> Dict[str, List[Dict[str, Any]]:
  grouped = {}
  for entry in entries:
    key = entry[attribute]
    without_key = entry.copy()
    del without_key[key]
    grouped[key] = grouped.get(key, []) + [without_key]
  return grouped

@register.filter
def further_extract(extracted: Dict[str, Any], path: str) -> Dict[str, Any]:
  paths = path.split(".")
  assert "->" in paths[-1]
  last, key = paths[-1].split("->")
  paths[-1] = last
  dicts = [extracted]
  for p in paths:
    parent_dict = dicts[-1]
    dicts.append(parent_dict[p])

  to_alter = dicts[-2]
  assert isinstance(to_alter, list)
  extracted_entry = extract_and_group(to_alter, key)
  dicts[-2][last] = extracted_entry

  return extracted
```

Which you could use (rather nastily) in a template by going:

```
plans|extract_and_group:"code"|further_extract:"name"|further_extract:"name->plan_type"|further_extract:"name.plan_type->hour"
```

I used type hints here for readability, but if you're not on python 3.8+, you can remove.
Anyway, I haven't tested this, and it's a bit ugly, but I guess it's an option?

Of course you don't have to do this within the template, so if my assumption is incorrect, you could adapt the above code to not be within a filter?

Hope this is a starting point.

Comment: Thank you for your input. That actually gave me a way to think.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys! Figured it out:

```
    #making a dict with production plans
    a = {plan['code']:{
            pt['plan_type']:{
                p['hour']:{
                    'layer':p['layer'],'val':p['val']
                } for p in plans if p['code'] == pt['code'] and p['plan_type'] == pt['plan_type']
            } for pt in plans if plan['code'] == pt['code']
        } for plan in plans}

    #making separate dict for names
    names = {plan['code']:plan['name'] for plan in plans}

    #'merging' those dicts
    for tt in a:
        a[tt]['name'] = names[tt]
```

KISS principle as advised.